# How to add textfields to JFrame by clicking a button?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I am trying to make a little GUI that calculates GPA of user-entered class. However, I got stuck when trying to add more text fields to the Frame by clicking on the "add a new class" button. When I clicked it nothing happens. I used a panel to contain the text fields and set up the clicking action to add the panel to my frame, but that does not seem to work. What is wrong w/ my code? Any answer greatly appreciated!

```
public class gpaCalculator extends JFrame{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel1;
    /**private JLabel creditHourLabel;
    private JLabel nameLabel;
    private JLabel calculatedGPALabel;
    private JLabel gradeLabel;
    private JComboBox courseCreditHour;
    private JTextField courseName;
    private JComboBox courseGrade;
    private JComboBox courseType;
    private JTextField calculatedGPA;**/


    private JButton addNewCourse;
    private JButton finishedCalculate;
    /**Courses**/
    public gpaCalculator()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(300, 600);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        addNewCourse = new JButton("Add a new course!");
        addNewCourse.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


        finishedCalculate = new JButton("Finished, Please tell me my GPA!");


        this.add(addNewCourse);
        this.add(finishedCalculate);
        this.add(panel1);

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent args){


            String[] courseCreditHourCombo = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
            String[] courseGradeCombo = {"A+", "A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D", "E", "F", "U"};
            String[] courseTypeCombo = {"Have taken", "Currently taking", "Will be taking"};
            JLabel creditHourLabel = new JLabel ("Course credit houe");
            JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Course name: ");
            JLabel calculatedGPALabel = new JLabel("Calculated GPA");
            JLabel gradeLabel = new JLabel("Course grade ");
            JComboBox courseCreditHour = new JComboBox(courseCreditHourCombo);
            JTextField courseName = new JTextField(10);
            JComboBox courseGrade = new JComboBox(courseGradeCombo);
            JComboBox courseType = new JComboBox(courseTypeCombo);
            JTextField calculatedGPA = new JTextField(10);

            panel1.setSize(100, 100);
            panel1.add(nameLabel);
            panel1.add(courseName);
            panel1.add(creditHourLabel);
            panel1.add(courseCreditHour);
            panel1.add(gradeLabel);
            panel1.add(courseGrade);            

            panel1.setLocation(0, 0);
            panel1.setVisible(true);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Try calling `panel1,revalidate();` at the end of your `ActionListener` implementation. Also, change `JPanel panel1` in your constructor to just `panel1`, at the moment you're not initializing the field as intended and will get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Also, consider using a `CardLayout` instead